# can a function be static and non-static in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

Lets say I have this class:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def test(self, b):
        if isinstance(self, Test):
            return self.a + b
        else:
            return self + b
```

This would ideally in my world do this:

```
>>> Test.test(1,2)
3
>>> Test(1).test(2)
3
```

Now this doesn't work because you get this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method test() must be called with Test instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

In python3 this works fine, and I have the sneaking suspicion this is possible with a decorator in python2 but my python foo isn't strong enough to get that to work.

**Plot Twist**: So what happens when I need something on self when it's not called statically.

Comment: whoops just adding the `@staticmethod` decorator works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something that will actually receive `self` if called on an instance, but can also be called on the class, writing your own descriptor type may be advisable:

```
import types

class ClassOrInstanceMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            instance = owner
        return self.wrapped.__get__(instance, owner)

class demo(object):
    @ClassOrInstanceMethod
    def foo(self):
        # self will be the class if this is called on the class
        print(self)
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/PVcjXk)

For the original version of your question, you could just write it like any other static method, with `@staticmethod`. Calling a static method on an instance works the same as calling it on the class:

```
class Test(object):
    @staticmethod
    def test(a, b):
        return a + b
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/tXpn5q)

Comment: But then taking into account the optional `self` parameter. :)

Comment: @albertjan: Static methods don't receive an implicit `self`, even if you call them on an instance.

Comment: Thats perfect exactly what I was looking for, does `MethodType` make a new "bound" method?

Comment: @albertjan: Yes. It can also make unbound method objects on Python 2; the `instance = owner` bit avoids that. (Also, I've changed the code to create the method object differently now, because the signature for `types.MethodType` changed in Python 3. This way should be compatible with both 2 and 3.)